# SMTPServerDisconnected in Google App Engine Standard (but it works in Flexible)

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, smtp

I am trying to switch my Django (Python) app from GAE flexible environment to Standard.

Everything works fine except, sending emails via gmail SMTP. It works with a version in a flexible environment, but it doesn't work in the same code as standard.

my app.yaml file includes:

```
    inbound_services:
    - mail
    - mail_bounce
```

My settings are:

```
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-relay.gmail.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'hidden@hidden.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'hidden'
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'hidden@hidden.com'
    SERVER_EMAIL = 'hidden@hidden.com'
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

The strange thing is that SMTP and the same email work fine in my other project with GAE standard with the same settings.

Comment: Is the app that works a Python 2 or is it a Python 3 App? Same question for the app that you're having issues with

Comment: both app is written in Python 3. The only difference is the app with issue is in 3.10 and the working app is in Python 3.11

Comment: Have you declared your `runtime: python39` and `app_engine_apis: true` ? 

Base on this [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/appengine/standard_python3/bundled-services/mail/django/app.yaml)